# Phonegap cordova.file is undefined

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, cordova-plugin-file

I have a Phonegap app in which I'm trying to save a file to the device's storage, but after I've included the plugin `cordova-plugin-file` in the config.xml file, the `cordova.file` object remains undefined. I am building the app using Phonegap Build using cli `cli-6.5.0`.

Using the Chrome inspector tools, I can see that when I try to log the `cordova.file` object, it returns undefined, logging `cordova` returns the cordova object in the log.

Here are the logs from the console as described above:

[image: Console testing]

The following lines are in my config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

This is the code I am using to save the file:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function(dir) {
    console.log("Creating file");

    var fileName;

    do {
        fileName = prompt("Please enter a name for your file", "");
    } while(fileName == null || fileName == "");

    dir.getFile(fileName, {create:true}, function(file) {
        console.log("File created succesfully");

        file.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            console.log("Writing content to file");
            fileWriter.write(imageBlob);
        }, function(){
            console.log('Unable to save file');
        });
    });
});
```

However this function never runs and I don't see any of the logs in the console via Chrome inspector tools. `imageBlob` is a Blob object containing a base64 image that was converted to a Blob object, but the code never gets as far as that.

I've also tried older versions of the plugin using the `spec` attribute in the config.xml file, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Ensure the file plugin is getting installed. You should be able to verify this in the PGB build log.
- Check cordova_plugins.js in the Network tab of web inspector and verify the file plugin is listed
- check that the file plugins javascript resources are also being loaded in the Network tab (File.js, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and after checking the build log on phonegap build, I discovered my version of `cordova-plugin-file` required a more recent version of phonegap, which needed to be set like:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/#phonegap-version